# Custom search query by category id

Tags: database, query, search

Soo I just made a simple search page. Its working! But i wanted to filter the results. The query that i wanted to make its like, it will search by the name of the articles and filter it, soo it only appears the articles from the category X (By ID).

This is my form:

```
<form action="<?php get_bloginfo('url') ?>" id="searchform" method="get">
            <div>
            <input type="text" value="" name="search" id="search" />
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
            </div>
            </form>
```

This is my query:

```
query_posts( array(
             's' => $_REQUEST[ 'search' ],
             'category' => '',
             'paged' => $paged
             )
          );
```

**EDIT**: Im kinda stuck on the category part. I know it doesnt work if it stays there empty.

**Attempt 1**

Tried to equal the category id and use it as a query

```
query_posts( array(
             's' => $_REQUEST[ 'search' ],
             the_category_ID() => '42',
             'paged' => $paged
             )
          );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
$args = array(
     's' => $_REQUEST[ 'search' ],
     'cat' => 'category_id',
     'paged' => $paged
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    //inside the loop
    the_title();
    the_content();
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Hope this help